# Why is "package" keyword sometimes separated by a comment from the package name?

Tags: perl

Analyzing sources of CPAN modules I can see something like this:

```
...
package # hide from PAUSE
   Try::Tiny::ScopeGuard;
...
```

Obviously, it's taken from `Try::Tiny`, but I have seen this kind of *comments* between `package` keyword and package identifier in other modules too.

Why this procedure is used? What is its goal and what benefits does it have?

Comment: Probably some whacky hack to hide the shacky pack from the [The Perl Authors Upload Server](http://pause.perl.org/pause/query?ACTION=pause_04about) to avoid some PAUSE processing that probably won't matter to you unless you intend to upload some hacky pack to CPAN which is probably a good time to learn about why people do it. In other words, I don't have a clue. :)

Comment: Just looked at the page  from your link and I suppose your point is very close to the truth :). It seems to be some kind of hiding from automatic processing. Probably an authoritaitve Perl fellow should tell us the full story why and when it's used/not used.

Comment: The comment itself has no effect; It's the line break that does.

Comment: @ikegami, firstly I was thinking from the language perspective and, as I know, there could be any amount of space between terms, so the comment was suspected in the first place; now after knowing the answer obviously the line break is the key point

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is indeed a hack to hide a package from PAUSE's indexer.

When a distribution is uploaded to PAUSE, the indexer will examine each file in the upload, looking for the names of packages that are included in the distribution. Any indexed packages can show up in CPAN search results.

There are many reasons for not wanting the indexer to discover your packages. Your distribution may have many small or insignificant packages that would clutter up the search results for your module. You may have packages defined in your `t` (test) directory or some other non-standard directory that are not meant to be installed as part of the distribution. Your distribution may include files from a completely different distribution (that somebody else wrote).

The hack works because the indexer strictly looks for the keyword `package` and an expression that looks like a package name on the same line.

Nowadays, you can include a `META.yml` file with your distribution. The PAUSE indexer will look for and respect a `no_index` specification in this file. But this is a relatively new capability of the indexer so older modules and old-timer CPAN contributors will still use the line break hack.

Here's an example of a `no_index` spec from [`Forks::Super`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MOB/Forks-Super-0.63/META.yml)

```
no_index:
    directory:
        - t
        - inc
    package:
        - Sys::CpuAffinity
        - Signals::XSIG
        - Signals::XSIG::Default
        - Signals::XSIG::TieArray56
```

`Sys::CpuAffinity` and `Signals::XSIG` are separate distributions that are also packaged with `Forks::Super`. Some of the test scripts contain `package` declarations (e.g., [`Arbitrary::Test::Package`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MOB/Forks-Super-0.63/t/02a-tie-enum.t)) that shouldn't be indexed.

Comment: Turns out to be exactly the kind of whacky hack I thought it was. Like the foundational shell script that ties the whole shop together and that's not been edited for twenty years.

Comment: Thanks. I had an assumption that it should be somehow related not to language itself, but who knows what hidden bits Perl has.

Answer (score -3):

Okay, here's another shot at this phenomenon ... I've been whacky-hacking Perl for a dozen years and I've rarely seen this packy hack and possibly simply ignored and never bothered to investigate. One thing seems clear, though. There's some hackish processing going on at PAUSE that's been crafted in the good ol' Perl'n'UNIX school of thought that without the shadow of a doubt involves line-oriented text parsing, so they parse those Perl files, possibly even using `grep`, but rather `perl` itself, who knows, to extract package names and then kick of some procedure or get some stats or whatnot. And to trip up this procedure and hack around its ways the author splits the package declaration in two lines so the hacky packy grep job doesn't have a clue that there's a package declared right under its nose and the programmer is happy about his hacky skills and the PAUSE stats or whatever it is they're cobbling together are as they should be. Does that make sense?

Comment: Honestly, no, not a lot. mob's answer makes sense. PAUSE is FOSS, by the way, see pause.perl.org.